# Area between a curve and a horizontal line

Tags: integration

I had 2 make 2 exercises which I found very similar but they have a crucial difference which puzzles me:

**1** Calculate the area of the plane $V$, between the graph of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{8x}{x^2+4}$ and the line $y= 1\dfrac{3}{5}$.

**2**  Calculate the area of the plane $V$, between the graph of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2-4x+5}$, the y-axis and the line $y=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

**1**  $\displaystyle\int_0^4 (f(x)-1\dfrac{3}{5}) \, \mathrm{dx}$

**2** $\displaystyle\int_0^1 (\dfrac{1}{2} - f(x)) \, \mathrm{dx}$

What is the difference between these cases which causes the different calculation? I am puzzled.

Comment: Your teacher is still using "mixed fractions" in calculus?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Why would it matter? It's not my teacher, but my book. However, it has been mandatory for 5 years to note fractions that way. We have to simplify them

Comment: Plot the graphs in mathematica, and you might be able to see the different between the two regions of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your standard formula for calculating areas between curves has the form:
$$
\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x)) dx
$$
where $f(x)$ is the upper curve and $g(x)$ is the lower curve. This makes the integral positive, since we want area. So, **draw a picture**. For the [first question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=8x/%28x%5E2%2b4%29,%20y=8/5,%20x=0..4), we see that for $x\in [1,4]$, we have $\dfrac{8x}{x^2+4} \ge 1\dfrac{3}{5}$. (For example, pick a sample point and note that $f(2)=\dfrac{8(2)}{2^2+4}=2 \ge 8/5$). Thus, $f(x)$ is the **upper** curve, which yields the integral:
$$
\int_1^4 \left(\dfrac{8x}{x^2+4}-1\dfrac{3}{5}\right) dx
$$

---

On the other hand, for the [second question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=1/%28x%5E2-4x%2b5%29,%20y=1/2), we see that for $x\in [0,1]$, we have $\dfrac{1}{x^2-4x+5} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$. (For example, pick a sample point and note that $f(0.5)=\dfrac{1}{0.5^2-4(0.5)+5}=4/13 \le 1/2$). Thus, $f(x)$ is the **lower** curve, which yields the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{x^2-4x+5}\right) dx
$$

Answer (score 3):

$(1)$ In the first case, $f(x)$ lies *above* $y$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 4$.

$(2)$ In the second case, $f(x)$ lies *below* $y$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

To see this, for each of $(1), \; (2)$, graph $f(x)$ and $y$, respectively. On the intervals $[x_0, x_1]$ over which you are integrating, the integrand is equal to:

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \;\left(\text{top curve}\; - \;\text{bottom curve}\right)\,dx$$